# How to use a CASE expression in the WHERE clause?

Tags: db2

I am using a CASE expression in my WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT *    
FROM    ASPECT.WR_AM_ADT_SUMM
INNER JOIN ASPECT.WR_AM_DLR_DTL
ON    AS_CNTRY_CD = DD_CNTRY_CD AND 
    AS_DLR_CD = DD_DLR_CD AND 
    AS_YEAR = DD_YEAR
RIGHT JOIN ASPECT.DEALER_MASTER
ON    COUNTRY_CD = AS_CNTRY_CD AND 
    DEALER_CDE_VEGA = AS_DLR_CD
WHERE
    COUNTRY_CD = '81930' AND 
    LANG_CD = '02' AND 
    (CASE PARM_ADTR_ID 
       WHEN 'ALL' THEN (AS_ADTR_ID_P IS NULL OR AS_ADTR_ID_P LIKE '%') 
       ELSE AS_ADTR_ID_P LIKE LOC_ADTR_ID 
    END) AND 
    DEALER_CDE_VEGA LIKE '8%'
    ;
```

In the above query when I pass 'ALL' in PARM_ADTR_ID input parameter then first condition should work, otherwise the second condition should work.

As of now it's giving the syntax error, could anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: 1] Save yourself some future headaches, and always make the `FROM` reference a tables with rows guaranteed to be there, and anything "optional" `LEFT JOIN`ed (essentially, flip some of your current references). 2] Never use `SELECT *`, always explicitly list your output columns.  3] The "all" condition is unnecessary, so long as `AS_ADTR_ID_P` is never empty.  `LIKE` without a wildcard is the same as `=`. 4] **WHAT** is the syntax error?  Required information, and likely a big clue to you.  However, I expect it's complaining that `PARM_ADTR_ID` isn't actually referenced as a host variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can a logical test that results in a boolean value as the **result- rexpression** to the right of the `THEN` in a case expression.

I usually do this without a case statement

```
WHERE
    COUNTRY_CD = '81930' 
    and LANG_CD = '02'  
    and DEALER_CDE_VEGA LIKE '8%'
    and ( PARM_ADTR_ID = 'ALL' 
           or AS_ADTR_ID_P LIKE LOC_ADTR_ID 
        )
```

Only one of the `OR` clauses need to be true.  Though I'd expect to see `PARM_ADTR_ID` twice like so:

```
WHERE
    COUNTRY_CD = '81930' 
    and LANG_CD = '02'  
    and DEALER_CDE_VEGA LIKE '8%'
    and ( PARM_ADTR_ID = 'ALL' 
           or AS_ADTR_ID_P LIKE parm_adtr_id 
        )
```

Comment: If `parm_adtr_id` is supposed to be a mask, putting `ALL` into it to mean `%` might be confusing. How would one use it to search for the actual value of `'ALL'` then?